# flutter: refetch data from SharedPreferences when app was opened in other android tab (when getting shared data from other app)

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

In other words I'd like to create persistent storage for my List.

What I'm doing now:

I have 2 methods, initial set up

```
_getDataFromStorage() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    List<String> wordsListStrings = prefs.getStringList('_wordsList');
    Map<int, String> wordsMap = wordsListStrings.asMap();

    setState(() {
      wordsMap.forEach((key, word) {
        Map<String, dynamic> decoded = jsonDecode(word);

        _wordsList.add(Word.fromJson(decoded));
      });
    });
  }
```

and the one that occurs when other app opens my app.

```
getSharedText() async {
    var sharedData = await platform.invokeMethod("getSharedText");

    if (sharedData != null) {
      _wordsList.add(Word(sharedData));

      SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

      List<String> wordsListString = _wordsList.map((word) {
        return jsonEncode(word);
      }).toList();
      prefs.setStringList('_wordsList', wordsListString);

      setState(() {
      });
    }
  }
```

Issue that I face:

Sometimes app can be opened from other app, don't know how it is properly called, by it looks like my app is overlaying on other app. In this cases I have 2 apps opened, and one of them may have outdated data.

[image]

Now I'm seeing the solution as refetching data on switching between android apps tabs, and my question - is there an event for that? Or maybe better solution for the case?

Comment: what do you mean by 'opened from other app'?  I never thought it is possible to open flutter app from another app. Is it calling the same MyApp instance or not?

Comment: you may see the picture, when I invoke some action from chrome, to share data with my app, it opens as "app in the app", and by pressing "back button" it returns back to chrome. And during all that time, another instance of the app is always opened. To answer your question - yes, it is the same app, but it seems like there are executed 2 different instances of it